# How to remove checkerboard artefacts with opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

I'm solving the image segmentation task with tf keras with U-net. In output I'm getting images with checkerboard artefacts like this:
[image]

How can I decrease artefacts with OpenCV?

Comment: You can try morphological operations using a horizontal and vertical structural elements

Comment: Are you tiling your input image to reach the full resolution? Make sure the the input is as big as the receptive field of the DNN, so that there is no border interpolation necessary..Then you should see smooth borders between the patches.

Comment: No, I resize big images (5-30 mp, different sizes and ratios) to 1024*1024, then resize this back, It also reduces the quality. I want to try training on random crops.

Comment: in your place i'd wonder why nobody else sees these things with U-net, or *if* this is normal, how the authors (of U-net) recommend dealing with it.

Comment: Probably not, because this is a very old architecture, in those days, hardly anyone tried high-resolution images. 
Perhaps the problem is solved by increasing the training time, but I have limited resources

Answer (score 0):

[medianBlur](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga564869aa33e58769b4469101aac458f9) filter my help:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('checkerboard_artefacts.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read the input image as grayscale.

blured_img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 31)  # Apply median filter with size 31x31 (relatively large size).
```

---

Output:
[image]

---

In case you don't want to loose too much data, you may use closing (or dilate) morphological operation before the median filter:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('checkerboard_artefacts.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read the input image as grayscale.

img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8))
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 21)
```

---

Output:
[image]